# Wrap text with HTML

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap entire content of a an element with a `<textarea>` tag, minus the element that is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Some text
    <ul>
        <li>more content</li> 
    </ul>
    <span id="click2wrap"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#click2wrap', function() {
    var wrapped = $(this).parent().text();
    $(wrapped).wrap('<textarea></textarea>'); 
});
```

So, my function is currently looking like this and when #click2wrap is clicked it must result in:

```
<div>
    <textarea>
    Some text
    <ul>
        <li>more content</li> 
    </ul>
    </textarea>
    <span id="click2wrap"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you currently see when you click your element?

Comment: $(this).parent().children().not(this).wrap('<textarea/>');

Comment: you cant wrap a `<ul>` with a `<textarea>` element

Comment: those don't work b/c the 'Some text' part is not wrapped inside <textarea>

Comment: @indubitablee I don't know what HTML or text will be inside parent...

Answer (score 2):

At first you can't see the parent html code in `textarea`. To access an `id` of element you should use `#` symbol. It means

```
$(document).on('click', 'click2wrap', function() {
    var wrapped = $(this).parent().text();
    $(wrapped).wrap('<textarea></textarea>'); 
});
```

should be changed to

```
$(document).on('click', '#click2wrap', function() {
    var wrapped = $(this).parent().text();
    $(wrapped).wrap('<textarea></textarea>'); 
});
```

To access to `div` element use `.parent()` function and for `ul` element use `.prev()` function.

Change

```
 $(document).on('click', '#click2wrap', function() {
     var wrapped = $(this).parent().text();
     $(wrapped).wrap('<textarea></textarea>'); 
 });
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '#click2wrap', function() {
     var wrapped = $(this).prev();
     $(wrapped).wrap('<textarea></textarea>'); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wrapInner` function. Also, had to add a couple tags to your jquery: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4829cm1k/2/)

Because textarea cannot display html tags, you need to get the value of the text area (which has html tags) and re-input that value back into the textarea while stripping the tags.

```
$(document).on('click', '#click2wrap', function () {
    var wrapped = $('#click2wrap').parent();
    $('#click2wrap').text('');
    $(wrapped).wrapInner('<textarea></textarea>');
    $('textarea').text($('textarea').text());
});
```

Comment: I don't know what is going to be withing this parent. It may be just text or HTML. I'm OK to strip HTML tags, but I do need to wrap all, so the function needs to be flexible enough to grab it all.

Comment: Please see updated answer. I added the last line and that should work for you.